# how to select parent based on value of its child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side

i Want to select all parent element based on the value of child input value in j query

which i can do that from this command

```
$(".XXXX tr").has("input.YYYYYY[value = 36816323]")
```

and it works fine but now i want to select all parent whose child input have value greater than 36816323 so i modify according to it

```
$(".XXXX tr").has("input.YYYYYY[value >= 36816323]")
```

but now its giving error unrecognized expression

any help will be appreciated

Comment: `$('input.YYYYYY').filter(function() {
    return +$(this).val() > 36816323;
}).closest('tr');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.filter()` method:

```js
$(".XXXX tr").filter(function(){
  return +$(this).find('input').val() > 36816323;
}).css('background', 'yellow');
```

Here `.filter()` lets you filter the specific `tr` elements which contains an input with value of more than `36816323`. But remember to parse the input value as number either with leading `+` or `parseInt(val, 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
$(".XXXX tr").has("input.YYYYYY").filter(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).val()) > 36816323;
}).closest("tr");
```

- Filter through each input.
- Then convert it to number.
- Then return the parent tr after comparing the value.